# Return object in Firebase ( Database ) Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get a user object from the Firebase Database, but is returning `null`.

```
public class Usuario {

private String id;
private String nome;
private String email;
private String senha;


enter code public void recover( String id ){
    DatabaseReference firebaseDB = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase();
    firebaseDB = firebaseDB.child( "usuarios" ).child( id );
    firebaseDB.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if( dataSnapshot.exists() ) {
                recoverData(dataSnapshot);

            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w("ERROR", "Error 01", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
}
```

All data for user class

```
 public void recoverData ( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot ){

    Usuario usuarioBase = dataSnapshot.getValue( Usuario.class );

    this.setNome( usuarioBase.getNome() );
    this.setEmail( usuarioBase.getEmail() );
    this.setId( usuarioBase.getId() );
    this.setSenha( usuarioBase.getSenha() );
}
```

I want to call the `user.recoverData()` method in a class, and then the find the method in the database and fill in the object.

Structure of the bank !

https://i.stack.imgur.com/18RK1.png

Thank you all.

Comment: Please add your database structure, so we can look, what's going wrong.

Comment: Please add your database schema and responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: Help me plss...